# Laravel4+Bootstrap: Redirect::back() - not at the top, but at the bottom of the site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

I have made a site with Laravel 4 and Bootstrap 2.3.1.
It is a one page site with four section:

```
<li><a href="#home" class="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio" class="">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#services" class="">services</a></li>                      
<li><a href="#contact" class="">Contact</a></li>
```

At the bottom of the site, section contact, there is a form to send an email.
If there are validation error, i redirect back with the errors.
It works properly, except for the fact the it REDIRECT AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE.
i want instead that remain there, at the bottom of the page.
How can i do this in laravel 4?

This the simple Redirecting code:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . '#contact')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is not working. It redirects to index.php, displaying a blank page.

Comment: What is your page url? And where does it get submitted? Does it submit to the same url as itself using POST verb?

Comment: Right now i am working on localhost and the full address is:
http://localhost:8080/Portfolio_Laravel/public/

Using URL::previous() it redirects to:
http://localhost:8080/Portfolio_Laravel/public/index.php

Yes Route::post redirect to the same url ('/')

Comment: In that case I would play around with [Redirector](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Redirector.html) or [URL](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html) and see which one works. I still think you will need to manually append the hashtag(#). Otherwise you will need javascript/jQuery to do so.

Comment: Yes, it's probably an issue with the hashtag and if you still can't resolve it, you should go with js/jQuery to scroll the page for you.

Comment: SHAME ON ME! Somehow i have deleted the 'return' from that line of code while copying. JofryHS: Your code works perfectly! It redirect properly to: http://localhost:8080/Portfolio_Laravel/public/#contact
Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. I was a bit suspicious when your page display blank page for you. I'll post this as an answer in case someone had the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the anchor tag with hash tag (#) is used to scroll through sections in one page using ID, you will need to re-append your hash tag (#). You can use `URL::previous()` to go back to previous URL and append `#contact`:

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . '#contact')
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors($validation);
```